# How do I obtain the reference of a getter/setter method created through @property in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to bind some QWidgets to the attributes of an existing class in **Python 3** so that any changes made through the GUI are applied to the underlying data objects in a clean and simple fashion.

My existing class looks like this (simplified):

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self._health = 100

    @property
    def health(self):
        return self._health

    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        self._health = value
```

**PyQt5** allows connecting Qt signals to any method, so I can easily achieve my goal by calling `someWidget.valueChanged.connect(player.someSetterMethod)`.

However, I use `@property` and thus, the setter name is identical to the attribute name. When I try using `player.health`, it is interpreted as an integer (as expected, but obviously not what I want here).

I am aware that I could define getter/setter methods with custom names and then use `property()` instead of `@property`, but I am hoping there is a way of obtaining the reference to the setter method so that I can pass it to `connect()`.

Thank you!

Edit: I doubt it is relevant to this question, but perhaps I should add that in the next step, I want to report changes that are not applied as received back to the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a `lambda`, because you need a *bound property* to get the right context:

```
someWidget.valueChanged.connect(lambda v: setattr(player, 'health', v))
```

Property objects do have `.fget` and `.fset` attributes, and the property object itself can be accessed on the class:

```
Player.health.fset
Player.health.fget
```

but these give you access to the original *unbound* function objects, which require the `self` parameter still.

You could use those functions too, but then you'd have to bind them to your instance first:

```
someWidget.valueChanged.connect(Player.health.fset.__get__(player))
```

The [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) on the function (which is a [*descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)) to provide you with a bound method which passes in the `self` argument for you (the `player` instance object in this case).

Comment: While the lambda statement doesn't work for me (`SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment`), fset and fget are exactly what I was missing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops, that's the eggnog speaking. Lambda corrected for you.

Answer (score 2):

As seen here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

> The returned property object also has the attributes fget, fset, and fdel corresponding to the constructor arguments

So you can access the getter, setter and deleter via these attributes.
In your example `Player.health.fset(some_instance, new_health)`

In order to connect that to your signal you must bind the instance to the setter. This can be done with `functools.partial`

```
from functools import partial

someWidget.valueChanged.connect(partial(Player.health.fset, player))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me towards fset and fget! I somehow missed these while scanning the documentation. I assume that using __get__ instead of the functools module is the cleaner solution, so I am marking the other answer.